# Calling Google adds from Google Sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I have this script set up but I am getting a 404 what do I need to do to make sure I can call the API?

```
const scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
function GIdea(keywords = "Demo") {
    var accessToken = getOAuthToken(); 
    var CLIENTID = scriptProperties.getProperty('CLIENTID');
    var endpoint = 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v10/customers/' + CLIENTID +'/keywordPlans:generateKeywordIdeas';
    var requestBody = {
      "customerId": CLIENTID,
      "language": "ENGLISH",
      "geo_target_constants": [],
      "include_adult_keywords": false,
      "page_size": 10,
      "keyword_plan_network": "GOOGLE_SEARCH_AND_PARTNERS",
      "keyword_seed": keywords
    };
    var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      },
      'payload': JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options);
    var ideas = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    return ideas;
}
function getOAuthToken() {
  var CLIENTID = scriptProperties.getProperty('CLIENTID');
  var SECRETFORADS = scriptProperties.getProperty('SECRETFORADS');
  var service = OAuth2.createService('GoogleAds')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
    .setClientId(CLIENTID)
    .setClientSecret(SECRETFORADS)
    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords');
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    return 'No access to Google Ads API';
  }
  var url = API_URL;
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken(),
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "muteHttpExceptions": false
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "headers": headers,
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  return jsonResponse
}
```

Exception: Request failed for https://googleads.googleapis.com returned code 404. Truncated server response:     <titl... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 70).

I call the function in a Google Sheets cell and get a 404 instead of the results of the API call.